# Trying to get click function to work on website

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, click

Here is my website at http://tylerfurby.com - I am trying to get this following click function to work:

```js
$("#click").click(function() {
  console.log('clicked on #click');
  enterSite();
  });
```

It seems do be doing nothing at the moment, here is the HTML:

```html
<div class="interact">
<h2 id="click"><a class="enterSite">Click here to continue</a></h2>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</div>
```

And here is the function I am trying to have called within the click function:

```js
var enterSite = function () {
   $("#click").addClass('blur');
   $("#click").animate({ left: "100%" }, 2000,'easeOutElastic', function() {
      $(this).removeClass('blur')
   });
}
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Thanks, I made an edit to correct this in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is a z-index problem. The #click is not receiving the event. Also, "click anywhere" should probably use $(window).on("click") instead.

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you! I'm new to z-index, and alas that's where the error was. I deleted the "z-index: -100;" in the CSS file. Thank you so much for your time.